# How can I select a record in a Grid and then post that record to an action in another controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax, jquery, grid, telerik

This is the architecture:

SearchController retrieves data and fills a Telerik grid. Rows are selectable in the grid. When a row is selected, I want to access the DataKey (AccountId) and pass that key to an action in EchoController.

On the grid I'm using:

```
    .ClientEvents(events => events.OnRowSelected("onRowSelected"))
```

The javascript looks like this:

```
    function onRowSelected(e) {
    var AccountId = e.row.cells[0].innerHTML;
    alert(AccountId);

    $.ajax({ type: "POST",
        url: "/Echo/GetPatientData",
        datatype: "json",
        traditional: true,
        data: AccountId,
        data: { 'AccountId': AccountId }

    });
}
```

The post does work, however, I'm not able to display the SearchResults view in the Echo controller. This strategy obviously is flawed.

Question: What is the right way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Arnold

Comment: You have not specified a callback function which is to be invoked when any response is returned. Check the $.ajax documentation.

Comment: Hi korchev. I'm stuck. What I really want to accomplish is to send the AccountId to an action in another controller and then in that controller return the View nto display account details. Is this the right way to go about it? -Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an example of something like this?

Comment: $.ajax( { type: "POST", url: "/Echo/GetPatientData", datatype: "json", traditional: true, data: AccountId, data: { 'AccountId': AccountId }, success: function () { window.location = "/Echo/SearchResults"; } }); } ....this code does not change the browser location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have moved on from this question. I'm doing things differently. Thanks to any who looked into this. -Arnold